# Use tkinter buttons to control a Python turtle in another window

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to use tkinter's buttons to control a turtle in another graphics window, but the buttons don't function

I was trying to use turtle graphics and Tkinter to make a simple program that controls a turtle with buttons. However, it seems that only one button is actually running a function, and even that is producing an error. Here is the code I wrote:

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle

global x
global y 

x = 1
y = 1
i = 0

root = Tk()

wn = turtle.Screen()
bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.up()

def goUp(event):
    y=y+5
    bob.goto(x,y)
def goDown(event):
    y=y-5
    bob.goto(x,y)
def goRight(event):
    x=x+5
    bob.goto(x,y)
def goLeft(event):
    x=x-5
    bob.goto(x,y)

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
middleFrame = Frame(root)
middleFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack()

button1 = Button(topFrame, text = "Up", fg="red")
button2 = Button(middleFrame, text = "Left", fg="red")
button3 = Button(middleFrame, text = "Right", fg="red")
button4 = Button(bottomFrame, text = "Down", fg="red")

button1.bind("<Button-1>", goUp)
button2.bind("<Button-2>", goLeft)
button3.bind("<Button-3>", goRight)
button4.bind("<Button-4>", goDown)
button1.pack()
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.pack(side=RIGHT)
button4.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: are you aware that the `Button` class accepts a `command` option?

Comment: I assume the `"Up"` command partially worked as you bound it to `"<Button-1>"`.  You should bind the other commands to `"<Button-1>"` as well unless you have a four button mouse.  I believe they will all ultimately fail due to misuse of the `global` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The TKinter `Button` class accepts a `command` option where you can pass in the function that gets called when a button is pressed. You also need to access the global `x` and `y` variables inside your methods.

Try this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle

global x
global y 

x = 1
y = 1
i = 0

root = Tk()

wn = turtle.Screen()
bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.up()

def goUp():
    global x, y
    y=y+5
    bob.goto(x,y)
def goDown():
    global x, y
    y=y-5
    bob.goto(x,y)
def goRight():
    global x, y
    x=x+5
    bob.goto(x,y)
def goLeft():
    global x, y
    x=x-5
    bob.goto(x,y)

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
middleFrame = Frame(root)
middleFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack()

button1 = Button(topFrame, text = "Up", fg="red", command=goUp)
button2 = Button(middleFrame, text = "Left", fg="red", command=goLeft)
button3 = Button(middleFrame, text = "Right", fg="red", command=goRight)
button4 = Button(bottomFrame, text = "Down", fg="red", command=goDown)

button1.pack()
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.pack(side=RIGHT)
button4.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Turtle's `Turtle` and `Screen` classes are generally used when turtle.py is used *standalone*.  When turtle, which is implemented atop tkinter, is used *embedded* inside tkinter, we generally use the `RawTurtle` and `TurtleScreen` classes instead.  You'll find more about this in [the turtle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html)

You also should review one of the many [online Python `global` keyword tutorials](https://stereochro.me/ideas/global-in-python) as you're not using it correctly.  Fortunately, we don't need it to implement this particular program.

Here's a rework of your code, as a single window implementation, that illustrates the above:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen

def goUp():
    bob.sety(bob.ycor() + 5)

def goDown():
    bob.sety(bob.ycor() - 5)

def goRight():
    bob.setx(bob.xcor() + 5)

def goLeft():
    bob.setx(bob.xcor() - 5)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

wn = TurtleScreen(canvas)

bob = RawTurtle(wn, shape="turtle")
bob.penup()

topFrame = tk.Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
middleFrame = tk.Frame(root)
middleFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = tk.Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack()

tk.Button(topFrame, text="Up", fg="red", command=goUp).pack()
tk.Button(middleFrame, text="Left", fg="red", command=goLeft).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(middleFrame, text="Right", fg="red", command=goRight).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
tk.Button(bottomFrame, text="Down", fg="red", command=goDown).pack()

wn.mainloop()
```